# Regex in Java to match a word that is not part of other word

Tags: java, regex

I have created this regex for this:

```
    (?<!\w)name(?!\w)
```

Which I expect that will match things like:

```
    name
    (name)
```

But should not match things like:

```
    myname
    names
```

My problem is that if I use this pattern in Java it doesn't work for the case where other symbols different than whitespaces are used, like brackets.

I tested the regex in this site (http://gskinner.com/RegExr/, which is a very nice site btw) and it works, so I'm wondering if Java requires a different syntax.

```
    String regex = "((?<!\\w)name(?!\\w))";
    "(name".matches(regex); //it returns false
```

Comment: Have you tried using `\b` instead of `(?!\w)` or `(?<!\w)`?

Comment: Yes, but did not worked also. I was afraid that the \b implementation was very dependent of the language (like, what would be considered as word boundary or not?)

Answer (score 5):

Why not use word boundary?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bname\\b");
String test = "name (name) mynames";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group() + " found between indexes: " + matcher.start() + " and " + matcher.end());
}
```

Output:

```
name found between indexes: 0 and 4
name found between indexes: 6 and 10
```

Comment: Thanks. But still didn't worked for the case where the text starts with "(name". I had to add the .* part as Bohemian suggested.

Comment: @silmarx I don't understand. Do you need "(name" to match "name" or not? With my Pattern it _will_ match it.

Comment: Yes, I need to match it. But using the code I posted in the question it was matching (it returns false):         
`"(name".matches(regex)`

Comment: @silmarx ... because you're using the method `matches`. The [matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) method will attempt to match the whole input for your `Pattern`. My approach was to iterate over the single matches of the `Pattern` within the input, and deliver each. So, my bad for not using `matches`, but unless you really need to match the whole input, you should consider using `find`, and possibly iterate if you believe there might be more than one match within the input.

Answer (score 3):

Use the "word boundary" regex `\b`:

```
if (str.matches(".*\\bname\\b.*")
    // str contains "name" as a separate word
```

Note that this will *not* match "foo _name bar" or "foo name1 bar", because underscore and digits are considered a word character. If you want to match a "non-letter" around "name", use this:

```
if (str.matches(".*(^|[^a-zA-Z])name([^a-zA-Z]|$).*")
    // str contains "name" as a separate word
```

See [Regex Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The problem was the .* that was missing. But I still don't understand why it is needed. In principal, the start of the text should itself be considered a word boundary, right?

Comment: The `.*` is needed because `matches()` tests if the *whole* input is matched, not *part* of the input as in other languages. Start of input *is* considered a word boundary. Without knowing what your input was, I can't say what is and isn't needed. I believe my answer to be the simplest and best regex for the task.

Comment: @silmarx `matches()` like Bohemian has explained tries to make a match over the complete input. To have the regex behave the way you expect you need to use `Pattern.compile("((?<!\\w)name(?!\\w))").matcher.("(name").find();` This would do a substring search for regex.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal or just use the `.*` as above. Surely `.*` is less code and effort than that long ugly chain of code.

Comment: Yes, of course. Not trying to refute your answer. Just elaborating on your last comment and letting OP know about `find()`. @silmarx, `find()` would only make sense if you want to iterate over multiple occurrences otherwise using `.*` is more convenient.